# list all vendors in azure ad who had logged/never logged in the past 24 hours

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I wrote a script to list all vendors in the azure ad to check if they are working or not. the script find the logged in users for the past day and if there is a record it should print, if there is no record and the vendor did not logged in or work it should print no login records. but my script is not working well any one can help?

###########################Here is the code ##################

```
#get azure ad users 


     $AzADUsers = get-azureaduser

#start for loop


    foreach ($user in $AzADUsers){


#list attributes 


       $dp =  $user.DisplayName
       $company = $user.CompanyName

# list of contractors/vendors  who didn't log in during the day.

    if ($company -eq "Vendor Resource - companyname1" -or $company -eq "Vendor Resource - companyname2" -or $company -eq "Vendor Resource - companyname3") {

        #check if they logged in the past 24 hours 

        $SetDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1);
        $SetDate = Get-Date($SetDate) -format yyyy-MM-dd
        $AllSiginLogs = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "createdDateTime gt $SetDate"
        $LoginRecord = $AllSiginLogs | Sort-Object CreatedDateTime -Descending

        if($LoginRecord.Count -gt 0){
            
            $lastLogin = $LoginRecord[0].CreatedDateTime
            
        }
        else{
            $lastLogin = 'no login record | Sick'
        }
    
    Write-Host "Last logon time  : " $lastLogin $dp $company
    Write-Host " "


    }



  }
```

Comment: what does not work? provide the error message... but I guess you have problems with the information from the signInLog? I would say the DateTime information is not correctly formatted. Also you should enhance the filter for the signInLogs to get only the events for the specific user, currently you get the log entries for any user...

Comment: I don't have error message but the code print for me all vendors with todays date and its not correct

Answer (score 0):

in addition to our discussion:

Currently you loop through the $AzAdUsers and query foreach the SignInLogs. But you do not filter the SignInLogs for the specific user, you query all the time the same information and select the latest entry from that log, but it has no relation to the current user.

You have to filter the SignInLog for the specific user, e.g.:

```
$AllSiginLogs = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -filter "Id eq '$($user.Id)' and createdDateTime gt $SetDate"
```

After that you could do:

```
$attrsht = @{
userId=$User.id
DisplayName=$user.displayname
LastSignIn=$LoginRecord.CreatedDateTime
}
new-object -typename psobject -property $attrsht
```

Btw. the AzModule will be replaced by the microsoft.graph modules. So it might be the right time to do the switch, which you have to do in any case until 2024.

If you do so, you can directly get the lastSignInDateTime from the user object:

```
#Switch to beta API
select-mgprofile -name beta
$lastSignIn = get-mguser -userId $user.id -Property signinactivity
$lastSignIn.LastSignInDateTime
```

In regards to you latest comment:
once again, if you want to know the last signInDateTime for a specific user you have to filter for that user id. if you filter by companyname you will probably get several users back and then you have to loop over this array of users and query the signInLog foreach user. the problem you are facing is that you miss to specify consistensylevel and countvariable, e.g.:

```
$company = "MyCompanyName"
$users = Get-MgUser -filter "companyname eq '$company'" -ConsistencyLevel eventual -CountVariable $null -property Id,CompanyName,DisplayName
select-mgprofile -Name beta
$lastSignInDateTime = @(
    foreach ($user in $users){
        $LoginRecord = get-mguser -userId $user.id -Property signinactivity
        $attrsht = @{
            userId=$User.id
            DisplayName=$user.displayname
            CompanyName=$user.CompanyName
            LastSignIn=$LoginRecord.signinactivity.LastSignInDateTime
        }
        new-object -typename psobject -property $attrsht
    }
)
```

You need to have the MgGraph module installed to run the above mentioned cmdlets -> install-module microsoft.graph

More information in regards to consistensylevel:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/build-advanced-queries-with-count-filter-search-and-orderby/

Comment: what if I filter like that would it works?    ----------------------------      $AllSiginLogs = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -filter {"(CompanyName eq 'Vendor Resource - company1')" -or "(CompanyName eq 'Vendor Resource - company2')" -or "(CompanyName eq 'Vendor Resource - company3')"}

Comment: if you want to know the lastSignInDateTime for a user account, you have to filter for the specific user account

Comment: can you provide me with a code that could be used for Microsoft graph api or any one could help :)

Comment: I did already: $AllSiginLogs = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -filter "Id eq '$($user.Id)' and createdDateTime gt $SetDate"

Comment: I mean I decide to use alternative way because AzureADPreview is not working on azure runbook so I decide to work on Microsoft graph api but I don't have any background, if someone knows and could attach a sample of the script that would be fine :)

Comment: the last code block is using the MsGraphAPI: get-mguser -userId $user.id -Property signinactivity... you can also work directly with the API by using invoke-mggraphrequest, docu: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: I found this code and it works, but how to filter the company names in the code for example if company eq google check last sign in .. || here is the code:   If ($Null -ne $User.SignInActivity)     {
        $LastSignIn = Get-Date($User.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime) -format g
        $DaysSinceSignIn = (New-TimeSpan $LastSignIn).Days }
     Else { #No sign in data for this user account
        $LastSignIn = "Never or > 180 days" 
        $DaysSinceSignIn = "N/A"

Comment: when I use: $URI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?`$filter=companyName eq 'google'" it gives me error msg that filter is incorrect.. but when I use: $URI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?`$filter=userType eq 'Guest'" it works!! could someone help plzzz